# How to create a multiline string or multiline label as a CGPath in iOS?

Tags: ios, text, core-graphics, cgpath

Does the API support this? If not, how could I do it?

There is `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph` in Core Text, which can translate a single character into a path. I could use that in a loop to create my string as a path, but I'd have to deal with spacing and kerning and all the other nasty things. I'm looking for a string path that would looks the same if it was drawn in a UILabel with same font and size.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article called [Low-level text rendering](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/Glyph.aspx) by [Ohmu](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=2887692) that covers this pretty extensively. I have tried this code and can confirm that it works.

It does use Core Text, though, so the rendering is probably not exactly like that of a `UILabel`. Also, the sample article only deals with a single line. To extend it to multiple lines, you have to setup the complete Core Text system. Instead of:

```
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString( attStr ) ;
```

you need to set up a `CTFramesetterRef` (`CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString`) and `CTFrameRef` (`CTFramesetterCreateFrame`) as described in the Core Text Programming Guide. You can then get all lines in the frame with `CTFrameGetLines()`.

You would then wrap the `for` loop in the sample article:

```
CFArrayRef runArray = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);

// for each RUN
for (CFIndex runIndex = 0; runIndex < CFArrayGetCount(runArray); runIndex++)
```

with another loop that iterates over all lines. The inner core of the loop should be identical.

The sample article creates a graphics context and adds the paths for the single glyphs to this context's path, but you can just as easily create a `CGMutablePathRef` or `UIBezierPath` and add the single glyph's paths to that object.

One thing that is not 100% clear to me without testing this is how to adjust the vertical position of the glyphs in the final path. You probably have to call `CTFrameGetLineOrigins()` to get the position of each line and add this position to each rendered glyph (possibly after transforming it with the text matrix).

Comment: I walked through that code, but can't find the part where it would be possible to get access to the individual glyphs in order to construct a multiline path of glyphs.

Comment: You are correct, that code only deals with one line of text. I will edit my answer to extend it (could take some time).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the UIBezierPath+TextPaths category in this project: https://github.com/aderussell/string-to-CGPathRef.

It shows how to create paths for single and multi-line strings and how to use them with CAShapeLayers.

The category is just a wrapper and the internal functions can be used in iOS or Mac OS X, you just need to link your project to the CoreText framework.